# How to add a double from a text field to a NSMutableArray xcode

Tags: xcode, nsmutablearray, double, addition, textfield

Thanks To all that helped problem solved. :)

For some reason this wont work for me please help

`array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

inputted = [input.text doubleValue];

[array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:inputted]];

NSLog(@"%i",array.count);`

where array is a NSMutableArray, inputted is a double and input is a text field
All that happens is that one saves but deletes the last one entered. how do i make it so that it saves everything entered?

Comment: if you step through your code in a debugger, is "inputted" the `double` value you expect?  What is the result in your NSLog?  "0"?

Comment: no the NSLog result is 1 no matter what i enter and no matter how many times i enter it

Comment: also if i do NSLog(@"%g",[array objectAtIndex:0]); when i enter 5 as the number i want to save it gives me 4.04411e-316 WHY?!?!?

Comment: Don't be frustrated here. It just sounds like you need to get accustomed to NSArray and NSNumber objects.  If you do something like "`NSNumber * firstNumber = [array objectAtIndex:0]; NSLog( @"%g", [firstNumber doubleValue]);`", you might have a happier result.

Comment: ok thanks man, dont worry not really frustrated just jokes

Answer (score 1):

You're always re-creating and re-initializing the "`array`" mutable array each time you go through your function so it's no wonder you are getting a result of "1" (one object in the array).

If you initialize your array once and only once, and move it *out* and away from the rest of that code (i.e. into a different function or whatever), then you will add additional objects to your mutable array and you'll see the count increment each time you add an object to your mutable array.

Makes sense?

Comment: Do you mean putting it into the veiwDidLoad because when i did it just kept crashing, should i put it into an if statement and only let it go through once?

Comment: Create and initialize your array only once... if you make it an instance variable of your view controller that's one way to do it.  Then you can add number objects to your array whenever you want and for however long the view controller object (and the array) are alive for.

Comment: If you're not using ARC, then you have to be sure to do memory management correctly. (Well, you have to get memory management correct even with ARC, but a lot of it is automatically handled for you.) I'm guessing the crash you were seeing was because you failed to do so.